# Angular distance Vs Angular displacement

Tags: kinematics

Are the two terms - 'Angular distance', and, 'Angular displacement' interchangeable for a uniform circular motion?

Comment: Both in this context mean the same thing; the portion of the circular path travelled. However, keep in mind that in isolation, 'displacement' usually denotes a vector quantity, whereas 'distance' usually the scalar magnitude of the displacement vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so - two and a half rotations would be the angular distance, while the angular displacement would still be a half rotation.

Comment: I agree, they are the same modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: Wait. When the object has completed 2π rotation, the angular displacement should be zero, right? So, in that case, angular velocity must also be zero? for one revolution, w=2π/T ?

Comment: "When the object has completed 2π rotation, the angular displacement should be zero, right? So, in that case, angular velocity must also be zero?"
No. B defn. Angular velocity is rate of change of angular displacement - which means we have to consider very small durations of time and corresponding angular displacement.
w=2π/T ? is not the definition, its just a convenience.

Comment: is the angular displacement zero in 2π rotation?

Comment: yes, $2n\pi$ angular distances, with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is equal to zero angular displacement.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of and understanding of Distance and Displacement has not changed between linear and angular motions.

In other words, if you have moved your leg 5 deg then moved it back, your angular distance is 10 deg and angular displacement is 0 deg